# SharePoint - Modified date for a folder is not updated when a subitem is updated

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, document-library, 2019

I have a SharePoint 2019 application.

I have a document library which includes some folders and there are PDF files inside those folders. My issue is, I need to show "Modified" column in the library's default view, which should show the last date any folder has been modified.

I have updated a PDF document and reuploaded it into the folder "Human Resources", however the "modified" value of the folder is not updated to today's date. When I go into the folder then I can see today's date as the last modified date of the specific PDF file. I need the last modified date of my folder to show today's date as well.

How can I provide this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that ***folder modified date*** only updated when we **create**, or **rename** folder in SharePoint library.

It will not include changes in the subfolders or files within the folder.

I checked following and it is not working.

- Create new file in folder
- Update file in folder
- Delete file in folder

> Disclaimer: I tested all of these myself and did not find any supporting article.